# Если пользователь нажал на ссылку ...a  rel="privet"..., то вывести информацию - как?

Tags: javascript

Нужен скрипт на Javascript, который бы осуществлял поиск информации в rel="*информация*" и если, там присутствует "privet", то скрипт бы выводил слово "Почему"?

Например, у нас на странице есть ссылки:

```
 <a rel="privet">Назад</a>
 <a rel="poka">Вперед</a>
```

Пользователь нажимает на ссылку "Назад" и на странице появляется слово "Почему" - в какой части страницы - не важно, но не во всплывающем окне (т.е. не с помощью alert). 
Если же пользователь нажимает на ссылку "Вперед", то ему ничего не выводится.

Comment: Куда выводил слово, в div или alert() ?

Comment: В div, а alert, как я понимаю, это всплывающее окно или что-то типа того. Мне нужен простой вывод слова в обычный текст.

Comment: задача бред \*.\*

Comment: AlexWindHope, а что Вы тогда предлагаете? Мне нужно передавать пользователям определенную информацию по нажатию на определенные ссылки.

Comment: Ну ппц вы сами почитайт ечто вы написали... Программирование штука логичная...

Вообщем - если, там присутствует "privet", то скрипт бы выводил слово "Почему"... Задача бредовая и абсолютна эллементарная в решении.

PS: вы почитайте свой вопрос и представьте что вы это читаете в первый раз и я вас уверяю, вы сами себе захотите поставить минус ^.^

Comment: AlexWindHope, я почти не изучал javascript, т.к. в основном пишу скрипты на PHP, поэтому задача эта для меня не элементарна. В Google ничего дельного пока что не нашел...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a rel="privet">Назад</a>
```

Первый вариант - срабатывает только по клику на нужный элемент

```
$("a[rel='privet']").click(function(){
    //делаете всё, что нужно, например
    alert('ку-ку');    
});
```

Второй вариант - срабатывает по всем элементам с проверкой на слово(более гибко, т.к. можно "на ходу" менять проверяемые слова)

```
$("a").click(function(){
    if($(this).attr('rel') == 'privet'){    
        //делаете всё, что нужно, например
        alert('ку-ку');
    }    
});
```

Comment: Более гибко и "более долго" ^^

Comment: Ну да, что уж тут поделаешь... Jq - он такой, да)

Answer (score 0):

Все очень просто :)

```
 <a href="#" rel="privet" onclick="alert(this.rel)">
```

Comment: Вы меня неправильно поняли. Нужно сделать вывод не информации из rel, а вообще другого слова, которое будет выводиться при rel="privet". И без всплывающего окна, т.е. просто текст.

Comment: Я не понял потому-что вы убого обьяснили, исправьте ваш ответ и будет вам счастье.

Comment: Исправил...

Comment: Понятнее не стало, складывается впечатление что задача эллементарна, вы не можете ее нормально сформировать и вообще вам надо учить матчасть :)

Comment: Еще раз исправил...